# d3 how to equalize the distance for the objects on the circumference from the center

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adithyavr/K6hvF/2/) . I have a center pie and circles around in the circumference. Till now everything is fine. But now I want to put text and image to all the small circles.When I add the text it is not uniform from the centre.

For the problem, I thought, I should draw few at a time maybe, each quadrant and adjust the width accordingly.But my total number of small circles are variable, therefore I don't know how many circles are there in each quadrant at a perticular time.I was hoping there is a more elegant solution which I may have missed. If anyone will be kind enough to share.

```
sub_circle.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'labels')
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
})
    .attr('x', function (d, i) {
    return (350 * Math.cos(scale_arcs_parent(i)) + 500);
})
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
    return (350 * Math.sin(scale_arcs_parent(i)) + 350);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is that the text anchor is the same distance from the center, but because its position relative to the text changes, it appears as if the distance of the text is different. You can mitigate this somewhat by setting the `text-anchor` depending on the angle.

```
.attr("text-anchor", function(d, i) {
        var a = scale_arcs_parent(i);
        if(a < Math.PI/4) return "start";
        if(a < 3*Math.PI/4) return "middle";
        if(a < 5*Math.PI/4) return "end";
        if(a < 7*Math.PI/4) return "middle";
        return "start";
 })
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K6hvF/5/). You can obviously tweak the thresholds for the anchor values to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described exactly how you want the text to appear (eg. position relative to the circles) so I have to guess.

You could use a combination of `text-anchor` and `dy` to keep the labels positioned relative to the circles.

```
    sub_circle
    .append('text')
    .attr('class','labels')
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .attr('dy','-30')
    .text(function(d){return d.name;})
    .attr('x',function(d,i){return (300*Math.cos(scale_arcs_parent(i))+500);})
    .attr('y',function(d,i){return (300*Math.sin(scale_arcs_parent(i))+350);})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K6hvF/6/

Comment: I want the labeals to be always outside the big grey circle. So on the right they will be right to the circle. On the left they will be left of the circle.